# Slice Method for Middle Values based on Length

Tags: javascript, slice

Using slice method with passed string's length / 2; Which  provides a float for odd-numbered strings/arrays and an integer for even-numbered strings/arrays.

I am looking for more background on how the slice method works as the length of string `Fiveo` is `2.5`;

```js
function sliceMiddle(s) {
  console.log(s.length)
  console.log(s.slice((s.length - 1) / 2, s.length / 2 + 1));
}
sliceMiddle("Fiveo");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on how `slice()` works.

You likely want to use `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` to get an integer position to slice an odd length string where you want (either after or before the middle character).

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(2.5));
console.log(Math.floor(2.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Any `value` passed to `slice(begin, end)`, javascript makes a best effort attempt to convert *whatever* input it is given into an integer. See [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.slice).

For converting `begin` and `end` to integer javascript does this:

> Returns the number value that is the same sign as number and whose
>   magnitude is floor(abs(number)).

So, these things will happen in such cases.

```
str.slice(1, 3) // from index 1 to 2
str.clice(1, 3.1) // from 1 index to 2
str.slice(1, 3.9) // from 1 index to 2
str.slice(1.1, 3) // from index 1 to 2
str.clice(1.9, 3) // from 1 index to 2
```